# Shorthand if else and anonymous functions

Tags: php

I'm trying to use an anonymous function inside a shorthand if else statement.

```
$str = (true) ? function() { 
    //do something
    return $result;
}
:
function() {
    //do something else
    return $result;
};
echo $str;
```

This throws a `Object of class Closure could not be converted to string` error since the shorthand if/else stores the function in the $str variable.

How can I get the function to execute and then have $str be set to the value that the function return?

I know that there is definitely a much easier and simpler way of doing this. But I'm stubborn and I just want my curiosity satisfied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use call_user_func

```
$str = true ? call_user_func( function(){ return "123"; } ) : 
              call_user_func( function(){ return "321"; } );
```

Answer (score 5):

That's not a "short hand if/else", it's the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary). Secondly, you're not actually invoking your functions, just assigning one or the other  to the variable `$str`. You need to actually invoke the resulting function.

Why you'd do this, I have *no idea*...

Comment: "Why you'd do this, I have no idea..." +1

Comment: Neither do I. I just felt like it. It's for something extremely simple , lots of if/elses that append to a string. I wanted to see if I could write it all in one `$str = ...`

Comment: @VitaliyIsikov Then just write it. The functions add nothing but overhead and visual noise.

Comment: @meagar There may be a good use case for it... closures can go out of scope and give back the memory whereas functions are forever (at least until the request is over)

Comment: @meagar but I agree ... the because "I felt like it" doesn't offer the justification to use this approach.

Comment: I'm just trying to challenge myself to think outside of the box. I know I can easily achieve what I want without doing any of this... but I wanted to see if I can come up with something else.

Comment: @Orangepill Seriously? Are you running PHP on a machine with 10K of RAM? Worrying over the memory consumption of a single function within a **PHP script** is insane.

Comment: @meager if the **PHP script** is running something like a socket server the ability for functions to go out of scope may be pretty important. I'm not advocating the technique... I'm just saying that there might exist a problem space where this is an appropriate solution.

Comment: @Orangepill I would argue that any problem space where this is an appropriate solution, you've already chosen an inappropriate language with PHP.

Comment: @meagar +1 I'll actually give you that one :)

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone finds it useful since PHP 7 one can invoke a function instantly upon declaration using a syntax akin to:

```
$result = (function () { return "Something"; })();
```

In this case you'd do:

```
$str = (true) ? (function() { 
    //do something
    return $result;
})()
:
(function() {
    //do something else
    return $result;
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `$str` to the function, not to its return value.  You need to actually call the function.

```
echo $str();
```

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator ends up assigning the anonymous function to the variable `$str`, not the result of the function's execution. So you'll need to execute the function.

```
<?php
$str = (true) ? function () { return '123'; } : function () { return 'abc'; };
echo $str();
```